# itterator_to_array() not parsing 50k rows

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using below code to fetch data from mongodb -

```
$collection = $this->db->xyz ;
$res = $collection->find($where);
$res = iterator_to_array($res,false);
print_r($res);die;
```

I am able to get 10 000 rows from the above code. But when I receive 50 000 rows nothing is printed. I don’t receive any errors.

I am able to die() before iterator_to_array but after that I get nothing. So I think the problem is in the iterator_to_array method. what can I do in this case?

Comment: Can we exclude `print_r` to be the cause? Try `echo count($res);` to just see if that gets printed or not.

Comment: @trincot not able to even die('123');

Comment: @RyanVincent How can i process them in batches. With limit and skip method or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: i have php error logs enabled but could not find any error.... each document contains 10 short string(25 chars) fields, this should give u an idea

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume each row is, shall we say, 400 bytes in size. Could be more (probably is), could be less.

400 bytes x 50k rows = 20MB

Chances are, that's more than the `memory_limit` setting allows, causing an error and killing your script.

There's a reason we have generators. They allow processing of data one by one to avoid such memory problems.

You can "work around" this problem by disabling the memory limit, but keep in mind that 400-bytes-per-row was quite a low estimate. The actual amount can snowball quickly. If each row were 1k in size, that's 50MB for the whole thing. 2k => 100MB and so on. You will very quickly risk running out memory on the server itself, and that's... bad.

Comment: Thanks. this is informative. But is there a way i can do something in php itself.

Comment: @AmanGupta Why don't you paginate?
Get the `count(*)` then break it in batches if it passes a certain threshold.

Comment: how can i break it in batches.... is there a direct method or i will have to do it using limit and skip

Comment: @AmanGupta I would go for check `count` then loop it with `limit` and `skip`.